# Ready event in Microsoft Outlook 2010?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-object-model

Is there an event in Microsoft Outlook 2010 which one can subscribe on, in order to known when Outlook has finished initializing and all components, folders etc. have been loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out what I needed to do...

```
...

private void ThisAddInStartup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    this.Application.Startup += ApplicationStartup;
    this.Application.ItemLoad += ApplicationItemLoad;

 }

 void ApplicationItemLoad(object Item)
 {
     //Do something   
 }

 private void ApplicationStartup()
 {
     //Do something
 }

...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869298.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about VSTO but good ol' COM addins get the `StartupComplete` "event" (via `IDTExtensibility2`) for exactly that purpose.

Comment: Thanks, found the Startup event in Outlook Object Model as posted above. The event is fired when Microsoft Outlook is starting, but after all add-in programs have been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. Usually, addins don't do anything that requires talking with many outlook objects till some triggering event happens (like opening a mail, or creating a new inspector) so THAT'S when you'd typically see some custom code hooked in.

In my addins, the code connected to startup does things like load up some config, and maybe connect to a DB (although even that I tend to do on demand vs once at startup).

Comment: OK, thanks for your input. In my situation I need to monitor certain stores and their location. I would to certain that all store have been loaded by Outlook, so I can check their location. This seems not always to be the case when the addin is loaded, i.e. when "ThisAddInStartup" is called.