# How can my Outlook Plugin (VSTO) detect when Outlook is fully loaded?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Thanks for looking.

I am developing an Outlook plugin that needs to prompt the user to log in upon loading of Outlook. I am currently accomplishing this by hooking into the `Startup` event of `ThisAddIn`.

## Problem

Unfortunately, the log in dialog is displaying before Outlook is fully loaded so it appears to the user as if Outlook is not loading and they are being forced to log in for the plugin.

## Question

Is there an event that can be subscribed to from within my plugin code that will only fire *after* Outlook has fully loaded and is being displayed to the user?

## Related links

[Ready event in Microsoft Outlook 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829687/ready-event-in-microsoft-outlook-2010) (The answer regarding use of `StartupComplete` event via `IDTExtensibility2` looks promising but I am not sure how to implement it. Any advice there is appreciated as well.)

## I have tried. . .

I have tried the following but this causes the dialog to launch too soon:

```
private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //Fire 3rd party code to launch log-in dialog here
        }
```

Comment: For the referenced question, add a comment under that answer asking for a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `Application.Explorers.Count > 0`. If yes, proceed. Otherwise subscribe to the `Explorers.NewExplorer` event and run your code in that event handler when an Explorer is shown.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, I have attempted to subscribe to the NewExplorer event, but it seems to never fire: `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Explorers.NewExplorer += OnNewExplorer`. Have I done this oncorrectly? Thanks in advance

Comment: The object that fires the events must be alive - you set up an event handler on a temporary variable created by the compiler. As soon as it is released by the GC, no events will be raised. Declare Explorers as a global;/class variable and set up the event handler on that variable.